# Laravel does not load subfolder from /app/models

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to arrange things properly in my app, so I created a folder called "validators" in my "/app/models" directory to keep my custom validation rules there. I expected it to be auto-loaded, but it's not. Here's the code of my validator:

```
class AuthValidator extends \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{

    public function validateActive($input, $value, $parameters)
    {
        if ( $input === "email" )
        {
            return User::where("email", $value)->first()->confirmed();
        } else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

}

Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    $messages['active'] = "You need to confirm your email first";

    return new AuthValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

It works fine, if i put it in /app/models/User.php file, so the problem is not in the class definition.

I tried to make a separated "/app/validators" directory and put it into composer.json and /app/start/global.php files for autoloading. Still doesn't load, even though I did "artisan dump-autoload" and "composer dump-autoload" both.

Every time I try to use my custom rule "active", Laravel says "Method [validateActive] does not exist.".

I also tried to write "echo '123'; exit;" in the beginning of my file and it didn't work, so the file is obviously just not loaded.

It's especially weird, because other custom models are loaded.

UPD: I use the standard files structure and right now composer.json is not edited.

Comment: Great, could you show what is your final structure, your files, what you added into `composer.json` and what is `validateActive` method? Without detailed question it's hard to say. Maybe you forgot to add method `validateActive` to your model? As I said it's hard to say if there's no code in question

Comment: Sure, sorry, I'll edit now!

Comment: why you're putting validators in models? hmm

Comment: @Cedie first, i tried to put it into /app/validators, but i can't make laravel load that folder, that's why, hoping that it'll load, i put it into /app/models/validators, but no.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a namespace?

This worked for me:

app/models/validators/AuthValidator.php:

```
namespace app\models\validators;

class AuthValidator
{
    function test()
    {
        dd("message from AuthValidator");
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
use app\models\validators\AuthValidator;

class WelcomeController extends Controller {
    public function __construct(AuthValidator $av)
    {
        $av->test();
    }
}
```

It autoloaded, I didn't have to add it in composer.json